# I have a stupid error like missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: math-mode, bibliographies

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{kn:TR\^{I}MBI\cb{T}AS}
{\sc Radu Tiberiu Tr\^{i}mbi\cb{t}as}:
\newblock {\em Analiz\u{a} numeric\u{a}. O introducere bazata pe Matlab}.
\newblock Presa Universitara Clujeana, 2005.

\bibitem{kn:B\'{E}LA}
{\sc Finta B\'{e}la}:
\newblock {\em Analiz\u{a} numeric\u{a}}.
\newblock Editura Universit\u{a}\cb{t}ii Petru Maior, 2004.
\bibitem{kn:SCHEIBER}
{\sc Amuraritei Gheorghe, Scheiber Ernest}:
\newblock {\em Analiz\u{a} numeric\u{a}}.
\newblock Universitatea Brasov, 1983.
\end{thebibliography}
```

**EDIT** Without the accents in the bibitem keys:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{kn:TRIMBITAS}
{\sc Radu Tiberiu Trimbitas}:
\newblock {\em Analiza numerica. O introducere bazata pe Matlab}.
\newblock Presa Universitara Clujeana, 2005.

\bibitem{kn:BELA}
{\sc Finta Bela}:
\newblock {\em Analiza numerica}.
\newblock Editura Universitatii Petru Maior, 2004.

\bibitem{kn:SCHEIBER}
{\sc Amuraritei Gheorghe, Scheiber Ernest}:
\newblock {\em Analiza numerica}.
\newblock Universitatea Brasov, 1983.

\end{thebibliography}
```

And the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,legno]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{combelow}

\makeindex \textwidth13cm \textheight18.5cm \oddsidemargin=1.7cm
\evensidemargin=1.7cm
```

---

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{kn:TRIMBITAS}
{\sc Radu Tiberiu Trimbitas}:
\newblock {\em Analiza numerica. O introducere bazata pe Matlab}.
\newblock Presa Universitara Clujeana, 2005.

\bibitem{kn:BELA}
{\sc Finta Bela}:
\newblock {\em Analiza numerica}.
\newblock Editura Universitatii Petru Maior, 2004.

\bibitem{kn:SCHEIBER}
{\sc Amuraritei Gheorghe, Scheiber Ernest}:
\newblock {\em Analiza numerica}.
\newblock Universitatea Brasov, 1983.

\end{thebibliography}


This is the main-file script:

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,legno]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{combelow}

\makeindex \textwidth13cm \textheight18.5cm \oddsidemargin=1.7cm
\evensidemargin=1.7cm

\newcounter{i}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\pagestyle{myheadings} \markboth{}{}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capitolul}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\include{T_lui-Weierstrass}
\include{I_Lagrange}
\include{P_Bernstein}

\backmatter

\pagestyle{myheadings} \markboth{}{}
\include{Bibliografie} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: The code works if I put only a \bibitem. When I try to put more items in bibliography it does not  work. in my main file I have \bibliographystyle{plain} and \include{Bibliografie}.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The argument to `\bibitem` should be a key *without* accented characters. It's used only for reference. Use `\bibitem{kn:TRIMBITAS}` in the bibliography part and `\cite{kn:TRIMBITAS}` in the document.

Comment: I've done it. It does not work either :(

Comment: there is another accent in the `\bibitem` argument `{kn:B\'{E}LA}` that needs to be removed.  also, delete the `.aux` file before trying to recompile.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was with the file .aux. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

The argument to `\bibitem` is just an arbitrary string that is used for referencing the item. It shouldn't contain any command, in particular no accented characters.

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{combelow}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Xyz}
\cite{kn:TRIMBITAS}, \cite{kn:BELA}, \cite{kn:SCHEIBER}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{kn:TRIMBITAS}
{\scshape Radu Tiberiu Tr\^{i}mbi\cb{t}as}:
\newblock {\em Analiz\u{a} numeric\u{a}. O introducere bazata pe Matlab}.
\newblock Presa Universitara Clujeana, 2005.

\bibitem{kn:BELA}
{\scshape Finta B\'{e}la}:
\newblock {\em Analiz\u{a} numeric\u{a}}.
\newblock Editura Universit\u{a}\cb{t}ii Petru Maior, 2004.

\bibitem{kn:SCHEIBER}
{\sc Amuraritei Gheorghe, Scheiber Ernest}:
\newblock {\em Analiz\u{a} numeric\u{a}}.
\newblock Universitatea Brasov, 1983.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't matter if you load the bibliography with `\input` or `\include`.
Note that I added `babel` with the option `romanian`, since it seems you're using this language. So you don't need to do any setting for `\chaptername` and similar commands; moreover you'll get hyphenation right.

[image: Chapter]

[image: Bibliography]

---

You may want to be able to type your document with the Romanian characters; if you save your typescript in UTF-8, you can type it as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{combelow}

% Romanian is not fully supported, so we do some adjustments
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{Ș}{\cb{S}}
\newunicodechar{ș}{\cb{s}}
\newunicodechar{Ț}{\cb{T}}
\newunicodechar{ț}{\cb{t}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Xyz}
\cite{kn:TRIMBITAS}, \cite{kn:BELA}, \cite{kn:SCHEIBER}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{kn:TRIMBITAS}
{\scshape Radu Tiberiu Trîmbițas}:
\newblock {\em Analiză numerică. O introducere bazata pe Matlab}.
\newblock Presa Universitara Clujeana, 2005.

\bibitem{kn:BELA}
{\scshape Finta Béla}:
\newblock {\em Analiză numerică}.
\newblock Editura Universității Petru Maior, 2004.

\bibitem{kn:SCHEIBER}
{\sc Amuraritei Gheorghe, Scheiber Ernest}:
\newblock {\em Analiză numerică}.
\newblock Universitatea Brasov, 1983.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

You can use `Ă ă Â â Î î Ș ș Ț ț` directly.